Securing free standing shower glass panel
I recently moved into a new house where the bathtub glass enclosure on one side of the wall is only glued with silicone and nothing else (no grooves or channels). The silicone on the bottom is bad and the panel can be moved by hand - very dangerous. I have two toddlers at home and I would like to make the panels safer. Any ideas on how to add extra safety to the existing panel with brackets or clamps?


Is the bathtub steel or acrylic?

Hi, I believe it to be acrylic

I am not a fan of drilling holes into things that are in wet locations.
To install a channel with removable stops requires that the glass height be shortened. If this is a tempered glass panel, you must replace the glass panel.
The only way this will work in your current situation is if you can raise the glass by 1/8", remove the existing silicone, install 4 -5 plastic shims underneath to support the glass and fill the entire void with a good quality mildew resistant silicone. This increases the grip area of the silicone to keep it stable.

Hi DelphicOracle, thank you for taking your time and answering. I understand about needing to replace the whole panel in order to add a channel. In your experience and opinion, are these panels that are installed with only silicone safe?

The panels are secured on the side and top, there is little chance that the panel will move much beyond what you are experiencing. You can use that to your advantage by moving the panel away a bit, cleaning off the silicone, applying a new bead, putting back in place and tooling the result to match the existing. If you can lift up the panel a bit with a suction cup while doing this to bed the glass in the silicone, even better.
